# Переменная из класса в jspx

Tags: java, spring-boot

Всем доброго дня. Сильно не пинайте, ибо не знаю, что ещё нужно выложить, чтобы решить проблему. Помогите пожалуйста, не получается вывести на странице jspx результат запроса из java класса. Просто отобразить то, что выходит в консоль на страничке, переменную stat. В консоли результат выходит как надо.
[GIT](https://github.com/tulitas/example-hiber-spring-database)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Pom.xmls

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>name.alexkosarev.tutorials</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>spring-boot-starter-parent</name>

<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>

    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

</properties>
<dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL for JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP,
        tomcat-embed-jasper version is not working, no idea why -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Контроллер

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@Configuration

@ComponentScan("com.repositories")
public class OptionsController {
@Autowired

private JobformService jobformService = new JobformServiceImpl();


@RequestMapping(value = "/options/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String options(JobForm jobForm) {
    jobformService.addJobForm(jobForm);
    return "redirect:/options";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/options")
public String getAllByWorkdate(Model model, String work_date) {
    System.out.println("CONTR get all by work date");
    List<JobForm> jobForms = jobformService.getAllByWorkdate(work_date);
    model.addAttribute("optionsList", jobForms);
    return "/options";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/options/delete{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String removeJobform(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    jobformService.removeJobForm(id);
    return "redirect:/options";
}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/options/getstatistics")
public String getStatistics(Model model) {
    String stat = jobformService.getStatistics();
    model.addAttribute("statlist", stat);
    System.out.println(stat);
    return "redirect:/statistics";
}

}
```

Страница jspx

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="2.0"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
>
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"/>
<jsp:output doctype-root-element="html"
            doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"
            omit-xml-declaration="true"/>
<html>

<head>

    <title>Statistics</title>
</head>

<body>

<img src="https://www.sherloglatvia.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/logo.png" 
alt="sherlog" width="90" height="50"/>
<h1>Statistics</h1>
<div style="float: bottom">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Montaz</th>

        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td><c:out value="${statlist}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div style="float: right">
    <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/options/getstatistics" 
method="get">
        <p>
            <label for="date"> Выберите месяц: </label><br/>
            <input id="date" type="month" name="workdate"/>

            <br/>
            <button class="add_button"> Pievienot</button>

        </p>
    </form>
</div>

<div style="height: 200px; width: 100px; border: 3px dashed #e03c32; float: 
left">
    <p>
        <strong><a href="/">Years list</a></strong> <br/>
        <strong><a href="/year2019">Month list</a></strong><br/>
        <strong><a href="/statistics">Statistics</a></strong>

    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</jsp:root>
```

WebConfig

```
package com.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import 
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import 
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/views/", ".jspx");
}
}
```

Страница, где вывожу данные из БД

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="2.0"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      >
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"/>
<jsp:output doctype-root-element="html"
            doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"
            omit-xml-declaration="true"/>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>

    <style>
        .navbar {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        .navbar a {
            float: left;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .dropdown {
            float: left;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .dropdown .dropbtn {
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            background-color: inherit;
            font-family: inherit;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn, .dropbtn:focus {
            background-color: red;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            float: none;
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
        }

        .show {
            display: block;
        }

        td, th {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        .remove_button {
            padding: 10px 15px;
            font-size: 24px;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            outline: none;
            color: #e60000;
            background-color: #00008B;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 15px;
            box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
        }

        .add_button {

            padding: 15px 25px;
            font-size: 24px;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            outline: none;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #00008B;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 15px;
            box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
        }

        button:hover {

            background-color: #3e8e41;
        }

        button:active {

            background-color: #3e8e41;
            box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
            transform: translateY(4px);
        }

        textarea {

            position: absolute;
            top: 98px;
            right: 450px;


        }

        table {
            position: absolute;
            top: 200px;
            left: 210px;
        }


    </style>

    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>


<a></a><img src="https://www.sherloglatvia.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/logo.png" alt="sherlog" width="90" height="50"/>


<br/>

<div style="float: right">
    <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/options/create" method="post">
        <label for="car">Ievadi A/M marku un numuru</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="car" id="car" size="40"/><br/>
        <br/>
        <label for="client">Ievadi klientu un tel.</label><br/>
        <input id="client" type="text" name="client" size="40"/>

        <br/>
        <br/>


        <label for="sistem">Izvelejies sistemu</label>
        <div><select id="sistem" name="sistem"> size="3" multiple="multiple"
            <option value="Optimum"/>
            optimum
            <option value="mini"/>
            mini
            <option value="comfort"/>
            comfort
        </select></div>
        <br/>

        <div><label for="work">Izvelejies darba veidu</label><br/>
            <select id="work" name="work"> size="3" multiple="multiple"
                <option value="Montaz"/>
                montaz
                <option value="Remont"/>
                remont
                <option value="Snjatie"/>
                snjatie
            </select></div>
        <br/>

        <div><label for="manager">Kas veic ierakstu</label><br/>
            <select id="manager" name="manager"> size="3" multiple="multiple"
                <option value="Agnese"/>
                Agnese
                <option value="Kristine"/>
                Kristine
                <option value="Aigars"/>
                Aigars
            </select></div>

        <p><label for="date"> Выберите дату: </label><br/>
            <input id="date" type="date" name="workdate" />

        </p>

        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <!--        <input type="submit" value="Pievienot"/>-->
        <p>

            <button class="add_button"> Pievienot</button>
        </p>

        <p><label for="info"></label>
            <textarea style="left: 210px" id="info" cols="60" rows="6" name="info">info</textarea></p>
    </form>

        <table style="word-wrap: break-word"  border="7">
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Manager</th>
                <th>Car</th>
                <th>Client</th>
                <th>Info</th>
                <th>Sistem</th>
                <th>Work</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>

            <c:forEach var="JobForm" items="${optionsList}">

                <tr>
                    <td width="75">${JobForm.workdate}</td>
                    <td width="50">${JobForm.manager}</td>
                    <td width="50">${JobForm.car}</td>
                    <td width="50">${JobForm.client}</td>
                    <td width="50">${JobForm.info}</td>
                    <td width="50">${JobForm.sistem}</td>
                    <td width="50">${JobForm.work}</td>
                    <td width="50"><a href="/options/delete${JobForm.id}">Delete</a></td>

                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>

</div>
<br/>
<div style="height: 200px; width: 100px; border: 3px dashed #e03c32; float: left">
    <p>
        <strong><a href="/">Years list</a></strong> <br/>
        <strong><a href="/year2019">Month list</a></strong><br/>
        <strong><a href="/statistics">Statistics</a></strong>

    </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

не понимаю что куда написать.
Примеры с выводом данных из базы нашёл в достаточном количестве, а вот просто переменную не могу. Либо криво ищу , либо не понимаю что искать. Делаю первые шаги в спринге и пока не очень получается.
Спасибо.

Comment: Не очень понятно что вы хотите сделать. Если вывести список на странице, то список каких обьектов? Я у вас вообще коллекцию не вижу. Приведите листенинг jobformService чтобы было понятнее что вы делаете.

Comment: Не получается вывести на jsp странице переменную stat, нужно отобразить результат переменной и всё, в консоли результат есть, на странице вывести не понимаю как. Со списком объектов проблем не возникло. Делаю первые шаги в спринге и не очень получается.

Comment: Я и пытаюсь от вас добится информации о переменной. Что это за переменная? Она часть списка? Она входит в коллекцию? Куда и в каком виде ее нужно вывести? Приведите в пример ожидаемый результат хотя бы.

Comment: getStatistics() метод, который запрашивает в базу данных количество совпадений и количество совпадений попадают в переменную String stat (например число совпадений 5).  В консоль я вывожу результат и он соответствует реальности. И проблема у меня только с выводом этого результата на странице браузера. Я не понимаю как эту переменную взять и поместить на jsp страницу в html коде.

Answer (score 1):

Для вывода одиночной строковой переменной воспользутесь:

```
<c:out value = "${statistics}"/>
```

Этот код нужно использовать вместо вашего блока с forEach (который применяется при работе с коллекциями, которых у вас нет).

```
<c:forEach var="statistics" items="${statistics}">
            <tr>
                <td>${statistics.stat}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Comment: А спринг сам разбирается откуда брать statistics? IDEA подсвечивает statistics и даёт комментарий Cannot resolve variable 'statistics' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: Reports possible EL problems, such as unresolved references and invalid EL locations

Comment: Spirng берет его из модели. Модель должна быть в свою очередь связана с view. Убедитесь что у вас эта связь есть и ViewResolver корректно сконфигурирован.

Comment: Можно ли утверждать, что ViewResolver сконфигурирован некорректно если я получаю список записей из БД на странице в браузере? Но эту блинскую пременную вывести не получается. Чем я ещё могу поделиться, что бы Вы могли минимально потратить своё драгоценное время, что бы помочь разобраться человеку, которой полностью не понимает что делать?

Comment: Приведите нормальные листенинги, по вашим обрезкам можно заниматься только гаданием что у вас там за кадром реализовано.

Comment: Я добавил, посмотрите пожалуйста. Если что ещё надо, пишите. Ибо я в тупике.

Comment: А названия страниц? И структуру каталогов тоже.

Comment: Добавил пом на всякий случай и гит ссылку, может так проще.