# Вывод переменной на странице из класса

Tags: java, spring-boot

Всем доброго дня. Помогите пожалуйста, не получается вывести на странице jspx результат запроса из java класса. В консоли результат выходит как надо. 
Метод в контроллере

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/options/getstatistics")
public String getStatistics(Model model) {
    String stat = jobformService.getStatistics();
    model.addAttribute("statlist", stat);
    System.out.println(stat);
    return "redirect:/statistics";
}
```

Страница

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Montaz</th>

    </tr>

    <c:forEach var="statistics" items="${statistics}">
        <tr>
            <td>${statistics.stat}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

не понимаю что куда написать. Хотя вывести список из базы в таблицу удалось. Помогите новичку. Спасибо.

Comment: Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1051338/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-jspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скачал твой проект. Там есть что править, очень местами попутано, но сделал так, что на страницу выводится твоя статистика. Исправил метод:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/options/getstatistics")
    public String getStatistics(Model model) {
        String stat = jobformService.getStatistics();
        model.addAttribute("statlist", stat);
        System.out.println(model);
        return "statistics";
    }
```

И на странице сделал вывод

```
<p>Statlist: ${statlist}</p>
```

Теперь, когда переходишь на страницу статистики, ее нужно запросить, справа в поле выбора месяца введи номер месяц и запроси его. Увидишь то, что хочешь.

Comment: Увы и ах. Не помогло. Проблема глубже. Спасибо за ответ. Я, по неопытности создал дубликат вопроса, более развёрнутый, если есть время и желание, посмотрите пожалуйста. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1051338/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-jspx

Comment: А лог есть? И что выдает на странице? В консоли браузера что-то есть?

Comment: На странице изменений нет (после запроса), ошибок нет, в консоль (ИДЕА) выдаёт количество совпадений по запросу, корректно. В консоли браузера ничего не пишет.

Comment: А проект на githabe есть? Или сорсы где-нибудь?

Comment: https://github.com/tulitas/example-hiber-spring-database

Comment: Исправь return "statistics";

Comment: Тоже пробовал, не помогло.

Comment: Согласен, напутано. Распутаю. Спасибо тебе, милый человек. Я просто обязан тебя благодарить. Скажи, куда я могу отправить благодарность (хотя бы шоколадку). Я буду мучиться, если останусь должен. Адрес, мне нужен адрес. Твой, желательно почтовый, по имейл шоколадку нельзя послать, я это точно знаю, только буквы.

Comment: Да все норм. Не переживай из-за шоколодки.  Помог  и хорошо.

Comment: Дружище, можно подсказку? В приложении сделано так, что при нажатии на дату, вылезают записи сделанные на эту дату. А если я добавляю новую запись на этот же день или удаляю одну, то все записи пропадают со страницы. И если опять зайти через дату, то все изменения появляются. Мне только подсказку, что искать, что бы записи не пропадали? Как оставить активным запрос из базы пока я не поменял дату? Или есть решение лучше? Спасибо.

Comment: Ты посмотри реально записи в базе есть или нет? Сохраняются, удаляются, пропадают? А потом уже смотри в дебаге, что происходит в коде.

Comment: С записями всё ок. Может быть это сессию надо сохранять, по выбранной дате?

Comment: Походу у тебя не все сделано. Не нашел отдачи на фронт данных из таблицы с данными. Так что ты проверяй код. И в дебаг смотри. Там вроде есть кое какие ошибки, на которые нужно обратит внимание.

Comment: Извини за назойливость. Можно ещё подсказку и тогда точно надо шоколадку отправить. Если я не хочу, что бы создавался объект с таким же именем, что бы вылезало сообщение "Такое имя уже задано", для этого валидатор используется? Или аннотация какая то в энтитях? :)

Comment: Валидация используется для фронта, а в entity используется для того, чтобы в базе name был уникальным.

Comment: Дружище, можешь, пожалуйста, ещё один вопрос помочь? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058314/%d0%97%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-input-type-month-%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc

Answer (score 0):

как такой вариант? javascript на странице

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     function getValue(){

        table = document.getElementById("mainTableId")

        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xmlHttp.open( "POST", "MessageServlet", true );               
           xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
           xmlHttp.onload = function() {
                 if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                   if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {                 
                       document.getElementById(.....).value = xmlHttp.responseText
                   } else {

                   }
               }
           }        
               xmlHttp.send();
     }
```

а в рестовом интерфейсе соответственно просто возвращаем значение