# Значение для <input type="month"/> Запрос из БД по двум параметрам

Tags: html, mysql, spring-boot

Всем хорошего дня. Столкнулся с проблемой, сам ещё в песочнице и не достиг необходимого опыта. И я знаю,что решение простое и возможно я его видел в итернете, пока пытался его найти, но не понял, что это оно. Смысл задачи: на странице выбираю в календаре месяц он должен попасть в запрос и запрос выбирает совпадения по двум параметрам: по году-месяцу и по слову.
Не понимаю как задаётся значение для выбранного месяца и как его передать в запрос. Хелп, уже 4 дня тыкаю. Если чего то в вопросе не хватает, говорите, я добавлю.

Контроллер

```
@RequestMapping(value = 
"/options/getstatistics")
public String getStatistics(Model model) {
  String stat = 
jobformService.getStatistics();
    model.addAttribute("statlist", stat);
    return "statistics";
}
```

Cтраница .jspx где (как я понимаю) в теге input type="month" надо прописать name которое должно в запрос попадать. Ещё есть сомнение на счёт тега form.

```
    <jsp:root 
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    version="2.0"

    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" 

 xmlns:th="http://www.springframework.org/tags/fo 
   rm"
    >
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html" 
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:output doctype-root-element="html"
                doctype-system="about:legacy- 
    compat"
                omit-xml-declaration="true"/>
    <html>

    <head>

        <title>Statistics</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <h1>Statistics</h1>
    <div style="float: bottom">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Montaz</th>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <c:out value="${statlist}"/>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right">
    <form 
  action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/optio 
    ns/getstatistics">
            <p>
                <label for="date"> Выберите 
    месяц: </label><br/>
                <input id="date" type="month" 
    name=""/>

                <br/>
                <button class="add_button"> 
     Pievienot</button>

            </p>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div style="height: 200px; width: 100px; 
    border: 3px dashed #e03c32; float: left">
        <p>
            <strong><a href="/">Years list</a> 
    </strong> <br/>
            <strong><a href="/addnew">Add 
    New</a></strong>

        </p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    </jsp:root>
```

Запрос в репозитории куда вместо 2020-01 хотелось бы выбранный месяц засунуть. Если я в этом запросе не пишу and where work_date...., то выдаёт полное число совпадений по слову Montaz, если с, то синтаксическая ошибка

```
@Query(value = "SELECT count(work) FROM 
jobform where work = 'Montaz' and where 
work_date = '2020-01'", nativeQuery = 
true)
String getStatistics();
```

СервисИмплемент

```
@Override
public String getStatistics() {
    return 
jobformRepository.getStatistics();
}
```

Сервис

```
String getStatistics();
```

ДАОИмплемент

```
@Override
public void getStatistics() {
jobformRepository.getStatistics();
}
```

ДАО

```
 void getStatistics();
```

А когда я делаю примерно так

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/options/getstatistics")
public String getStatistics(Model model, String date) {
    String stat = jobformService.getStatistics(date);
    model.addAttribute("statlist", stat);
    System.out.println("montaz by month " + stat);
    return "statistics";
}
```

и прописываю везде String date где это связанно с getStatistics, и для input type="date" прописываю name="date", то получаю что класс абстрактный и надо имплементить метод getStatistics(). И потом уже ошибка при запуске приложения

```
    2019-12-16 19:48:26.275 ERROR 19248 --- [           main] 
o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field jobformService in com.controllers.OptionsController required a bean of 
type 'com.Models.JobformService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.Models.JobformService' in your 
configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

И вот чего с ней делать, не понимаю. Хотя что написано, понятно

Спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: where work = 'Montaz' and where 
work_date = '2020-01' Второй раз where писать не нужно.

Comment: Владимир, спасибо за ответ и потраченное время. Я выше написал, что без принудительной даты выдаёт число всех совпадений которые есть в базе. А у меня не выходит передать выбранный месяц в запрос. Я может неясно выражаюсь, ибо не имею опыта профессиональной терминологии. Если мой вопрос Вам не совсем понятен, я с огромной радостью его перефразирую. Я действительно в тупике.

Comment: У вас синтаксическая ошибка в параметрах. Второй раз слово "where" в запросе  писать не нужно. Вот так: where work = 'Montaz' and work_date = '2020-01'

Comment: Спасибо. Это я понял. У меня проблема с тем, что я не понимаю как выбранный месяц засунуть то место где сейчас написано год-месяц.

Comment: это зависит от того как "на странице выбираю в календаре месяц" - что за страница, функция, данные

Comment: Да вроде в вопросе указал.